# DynamoDB put command is inserting an empty item

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing a nodejs/dynamodb application locally. I am running into a problem of putting in an item into the database. Creating the table works fine and when I insert an item it says the item inserted successfully, but shows an empty item was inserted

> "Added item:{}"

It should instead show the item has a username of 'bob' and a password of 'password'. I am using the most recent versions of nodejs, npm, dynamodb local, and the javascript aws-sdk.

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var createUsersTable= {
    TableName : "Users",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "username", KeyType: "HASH"}
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "username", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(createUsersTable, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});



setTimeout( function(){
    var table = "Users";

    var username = 'bob';

    var params = {
        TableName:table,
        Item:{
            "username": 'bob',
            "password": 'password'
        }
    };

    console.log("Adding a new item...");
    dynamodbDoc.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });

}, 4000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're seeing an empty item is because by default the [PutItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ReturnValues) api does not return the item that was inserted.

The DynamoDB api is very clumsy to work with, since you're using nodejs Id suggest having a look at using [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) which should provide a much more developer friendly api. To save your user data would be as simple as:

```
User.create({username : 'bob', password : 'password'}, function (err, user) { });
```

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for the response. When I use the query command to try to get the item it return undefined. So it looks like the item is not being put in properly. I will have a look at the link you sent thanks! Horrible if amazons own sdk didn't work properly.

Comment: The query api should be used to get lists of items with the same hash key and a different range key. In the example you posted, I only see a hash key and no range. You should use the getItem api to attempt to get this item by just the hash key.

Comment: I tried the getitem and still returned the same result.

Comment: I  having trouble understanding so is Amazons JavaScript SDK not working? Put and Get should work, otherwise why do they even have the SDK in production and available for developers to use? And so what is the difference between using Vogel and the SDK? Is Vogel built on top of the sdk? Cheers

Comment: The AWS javascript sdk does work, however the DynamoDB api can be confusing and complicated to use. The Vogels lib provides a simpler, developer friendly api which is built on top of the AWS sdk.